# Problemas com vetorização usando o compilador de C++ da intel no Visual Studio

Tags: c++, openmp

O código abaixo é fruto de um trabalho que estou desenvolvendo, basicamente é a multiplicação de uma matriz quadrada, porém, os resultados que eu tive paralelizando a aplicação com a API OpenMP foram superiores aos resultados que obtive usando SIMD da mesma API.

O que estou fazendo de errado? é a sintaxe?

Algumas informações que podem ser pertinente em identificar o problema: Estou usando o compilador da intel atravéz da IDE do visual studio, o OpenMP do visual studio é versão 2.0 (que não suporta SIMD) mas acho que é o 4.0 que vem com o compilador que está sendo usado. Enfim, pra mim é uma atividade nova (processamento paralelo) então se puderem esclarecer as coisas agradeceria de coração. Segue o código:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

int lin = 800, col = 800; // Valores de linha e coluna


int main()
{

    // --------------------------------------
    // Cria a matriz 1
    int** m1 = new int*[lin];
    for (int i = 0; i < lin; ++i)
        m1[i] = new int[col];
    // --------------------------------------


    // --------------------------------------
    // Cria a matriz 2
    int** m2 = new int*[lin];
    for (int i = 0; i < lin; ++i)
        m2[i] = new int[col];
    // --------------------------------------


    // --------------------------------------
    // Cria a matriz resposta
    int** res = new int*[lin];
    for (int i = 0; i < lin; ++i)
        res[i] = new int[col];
    // --------------------------------------

    cout << "criou matrizes" << endl;



//PREENCHE m1 e m2
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// BLOCO PARALELO
#pragma omp simd collapse (2)
        for (int i = 0; i < lin; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lin; ++j) {
                m1[i][j] = (i + 1);
            }
        }

// FIM DO BLOCO PARALELO

// BLOCO PARALELO
#pragma omp simd collapse (2) 
        for (int i = 0; i < lin; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lin; ++j) {
                m2[i][j] = (i + 1);
            }
        }

// FIM DO BLOCO PARALELO

cout << "preencheu" << endl;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------



    //faz a magica rolar

    clock_t timer = clock(); //valores de marcação de tempo


    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cout << "iniciou" << endl;


#pragma omp simd collapse (2)
    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < lin; j++)
        {
            res[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < lin; k++)
                res[i][j] += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "finalizou" << endl;
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //marca tempo final e exibe
    timer = clock() - timer;
    cout << "Programa Finalizado em " << ((float)timer) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " Segundos" << endl;

    system("Pause");
}

// This code is contributed 
// by Soumik Mondal
```

Comment: Porque motivo os resultados com OpenMP deviam ser inferiores aos resultados com SIMD ?

Comment: Porque além de paralelizar o processo, o SIMD faz múltiplos calculos vetoriais simultaneamente. Por isso o SIMD deveria ter um resultado melhor que o paralelismo simples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta pergunta é semelhante a [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674049/parallel-for-vs-omp-simd-when-to-use-each) feita no stack em inglês, e a resposta para ela é a [mesma que ela recebeu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14675507/3123894). De qualquer forma, como o propósito deste fórum é fornecer respostas em português, vou traduzir a resposta do @jonathan-dursi:

> O padrão fornecido pelo [link](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0RC1_final.pdf) é relativamente claro (pag 13, linhas 19+20)
>
> > Quando qualquer thread encontrar uma construção `simd`, as iterações do laço associadas com a construção podem ser executadas nas *lanes* SIMD que estão disponíveis para a thread.
>
> SIMD é uma coisa interna para threads. De forma mais concreta, em uma CPU você pode imaginar usar diretivas `simd` para solicitar especificamente a vetorização de pedaços de iterações de laço que pertencem individualmente à mesma thread. Isso está expondo os vários níveis de paralelismo existentes em um único processador multinúcleo, de maneira independente da plataforma. Veja, por exemplo, a discussão (junto com o material do acelerador) nesta [postagem no blog da intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/11/05/openmp-40-may-offer-important-solutions-for-targeting-and-vectorization).
>
> Então, basicamente, você desejará usar `omp parallel` para distribuir o trabalho em diferentes threads que poderão migrar para vários núcleos; e você desejará usar `omp simd` para usar os pipelines de vetores (por exemplo) em cada núcleo. Normalmente, `omp parallel` iria por fora do trecho de código para lidar com a distribuição paralela de trabalho de **granulação mais grossa** e o `omp simd` contornaria laços apertados dentro dele para explorar o paralelismo de **granulação fina**.

De forma resumida: SIMD isoladamente tem pouco potencial para ganhar de uma região paralela comum. A diretiva `simd` não cria uma região paralela.

Um código com SIMD será mais eficiente que um código paralelo se explorar melhor deficiências comuns como *cache misses* ou se tiver mais *lanes* que núcleos no teu processador, o que é bem incomum. Além do que, a diretiva `simd` é uma dica para o pré-processador. Não há garantias de que seu código será vetorizado.

Você pode ter ganhos se **combinar** as diretivas.

(e eu que sem querer respondi a pergunta em inglês ao invés desta :p )